Juniper MX204 Client Can't Ping from BGP
Sorry, a newbie here, I have topology like this
BGP (Vyos) --- MX204 --- Client (Mikrotik)
Between BGP and MX204 have iBgp connection and advertise 103.20.186.0/24 from MX204
The question is, why BGP cannot ping IP Client (103.20.186.10) but can ping the gateway (103.20.186.9)?
Here the result from MX204
show route advertising-protocol bgp 10.0.0.1 

inet.0: 241972 destinations, 278411 routes (241697 active, 0 holddown, 494 hidden)   Prefix       Nexthop          MED     Lclpref    AS path
* 103.20.186.0/24         Self    
                     100        I


inet.0: 241974 destinations, 278410 routes (241699 active, 0 holddown, 494 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

0.0.0.0/0          *[Static/5] 00:16:50
                    > via gr-0/0/10.1   --------> to BGP (Vyos)

Here from BGP (Vyos)
show ip bgp neighbors 10.0.0.2 received-routes 
BGP table version is 2387509076, local router ID is 103.203.189.5, vrf id 0
Default local pref 100, local AS 58553
Status codes:  s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
               i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Nexthop codes: @NNN nexthop's vrf id, < announce-nh-self
Origin codes:  i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 103.20.186.0/24  10.0.0.2                      150  32769 i

ping 103.20.186.10.                          ---------------------> IP Client (mikrotik)
PING 103.20.186.10 (103.20.186.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 103.20.186.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 34ms

Here from the mikrotik
ip route print 
Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, 
C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, 
B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
 #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
 0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          103.20.186.9              1

Thank you
